# How to convert p value of ANOVA into a range of 0 to 1 like Cramer's V?

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, inference, chi-squared-test

I was looking for a ***way to convert*** the p-values returned by a hypothesis test.

In the general scenario, we consider `p < 0.05` to reject the null hypothesis and more than 0.05 to fail to reject it. But when it comes to communicating with the end user, it is very important to *"somehow"* translate such values into the range of 0 to 1.

I've come across a technique called **Cramer's V** which translates the Chi-square statistic into 0 (corresponding to no association between the variables) to 1 (complete association) | from [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_V).

---

I might have misunderstood it completely, but if it is true, then I am looking for a *similar* way to translate the result of ANOVA and also the T-test (if they both have different techniques) into 0 to 1.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: The $p$ value *is* already between zero and one. Just report this and not the binary result "significant/not significant". However, note that the $p$ value is a measure of *statistical* significance, not one of effect size! If you are looking for an effect size, you need to do something different.

Comment: Agreed, the p-value is between 0 and 1 but here is a logic flip. The closer to 0 the lower the chances of the error, meaning both variables have an effect on each other. While in general value closer to 1 has a better understanding of "strong" association. With that logic, I want to somehow convert the values.

Comment: You may be looking for *r*-squared or *eta*-squared, as an effect size statistics for anova.

Comment: @SalMangiafico *eta-squared* looks really promising, and does it always comply with the $p$ value? Meaning, if a variable has $p$ value of **0.01** then it should have *eta-squared* closer to **1** than the other variable with $p$ value higher than 0.01, say **0.05**, will have a lower *eta-squared*?

Comment: Tests of significance (*p*-values) and effect size statistics (like Cramer's *V* and *eta*-squared) measure different things.  For a given sample size and statistical test, they are related.  But across experiments, you can have a small effect size statistic and a small *p*-value, or vice-versa.  They simply measure different things.

Comment: Why? p-values are well known throughout statistics, and while many people do not understand them, most people who do science have heard of them and will be comfortable with them. What is your goal in comunicating with the end-user? Why wouldn't $1-p$ work for you?

Comment: Another idea is to calculate post-hoc power.  Post-hoc power doesn't really provide any additional information beyond the *p*-value given the design of the experiment.  The following article, I think, covers the topic well, especially the included plots. [data.library.virginia.edu/post-hoc-power-calculations-are-not-useful/](https://data.library.virginia.edu/post-hoc-power-calculations-are-not-useful/)

Comment: @Dave, I was to use this logic if I would never have seen *eta* squared. Eta squared looks like it makes more sense as I want to report the "effect" of the association between 2 variables. Since I think *Sal* has given really a comprehensive answer, I have found a direction toward what I ***should*** be looking for. In the meanwhile, I've found a perfect article that talks ***just*** about this: https://towardsdatascience.com/the-search-for-categorical-correlation-a1cf7f1888c9

Comment: I've found a great resource: https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007/978-94-007-0753-5_918#:~:text=Eta%20squared%20is%20a%20measure,variables%20measured%20using%20different%20units. Start reading about eta squared from page number 234.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tests of significance (*p*-values) and effect size statistics (like Cramer's *V* and *eta*-squared) measure different things.

For a given sample size and statistical test, they are related.

But across experiments, you can have a small effect size statistic and a small *p*-value, or vice-versa. They simply measure different things.

Here is an example with a linear model (anova) and *eta*-squared.  Note that for a one-way anova, *eta*-squared is the same as the *r*-squared for the model.  Also note that for this model, the partial *eta*-squared is the same as *eta*-squared.

In the first example, the model has two Groups, *A* and *B*.  The *eta*-squared is 0.6 and the *p*-value is 0.07.

```
if(!require(DescTools)){install.packages("DescTools")}

A = c(1,2,3)
B = c(3,4,5)

Y = c(A, B)
Group = c(rep("A", length(A)), rep("B", length(B)))

Data1 = data.frame(Group, Y)

model1 = lm(Y ~ Group, data=Data1)

library(DescTools)

EtaSq(model1, anova=TRUE)

   ###           eta.sq eta.sq.part SS df MS  F        p
   ### Group        0.6         0.6  6  1  6  6 0.070484
```

For the second example, we'll keep the values for Groups *A* and *B* the same, but increase the sample size.  Here, the *eta*-squared is the same (0.6), but the *p*-value decreases to 0.00016.

```
A = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
B = c(3,4,5,3,4,5,3,4,5)

Y = c(A, B)
Group = c(rep("A", length(A)), rep("B", length(B)))

Data2 = data.frame(Group, Y)

model2 = lm(Y ~ Group, data=Data2)

library(DescTools)

EtaSq(model2, anova=TRUE)

   ###           eta.sq eta.sq.part SS df    MS  F            p
   ### Group        0.6         0.6 18  1 18.00 24 0.0001605342
```

However, if we modify the second example to make the effect size larger, with the same sample size, *eta*-squared increases (to 0.77) and the p-value decreases (to 0.0000016).

```
A = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
B = c(4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6)

Y = c(A, B)
Group = c(rep("A", length(A)), rep("B", length(B)))

Data3 = data.frame(Group, Y)

model3 = lm(Y ~ Group, data=Data3)

library(DescTools)

EtaSq(model3, anova=TRUE)

   ###              eta.sq eta.sq.part   SS df    MS  F            p
   ### Group     0.7714286   0.7714286 40.5  1 40.50 54 1.639535e-06
```

Comment: $Eta^2$ works really well, as I have found some rules of thumb about *"what should be called a high or low effect"*, I came to know that:  `<.01`: *Small effect size*, `<.06`: *Medium effect size*, `.14 or higher`: *Large effect size*. Now, it has become clear from my tests that I ran on some datasets that unless both variables are "obviously" highly dependent/related, eta-2 is not coming higher than 0.5, thus the rules of thumb are the correct. The question is, **whether there is any way to project the eta square into the range of 0-1 where `>.14` comes close to 1 while `<.06` to zero?**

Comment: For a model with perfect fit, the eta-squared will be 1.  Compare: `Y = c(1,2,3,100,101,102,200,201,202); Group = factor(c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C")); model = lm(Y ~ Group); library(DescTools); EtaSq(model); summary(model)`

Comment: Also, be cautious with those interpretations of e.g. "large" effect size.  Those come from Jacob Cohen, specifically for behavioral science.  They're not in any way universal.  In behavior sciences and in some fields in biology, relatively small effect sizes are relatively impressive.  Simply because there are many factors that determine human behavior or biological systems.  On the other hand, if you are doing something in analytical chemistry, you might expect an r-square of very close to one.